# What is correct way to tell jQuery validation to ignore an input based on class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Given I'm using jQuery validator on a page, something like:

```
$('#myform').validate({
  ignore: ".jqueryNoValidate",
  rules: {
    inputx: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    inputx: {
      "Required field - you gotta put something in here!"
    }
  }
})
```

I'm finding the validator plugin is still inserting errors elements for the input with the class 'jqueryNoValidate'.

```
  <label for="" class="error"></label>
```

The input itself does not have a name/id as it will be getting cloned, and those clones added/removed from the DOM so didn't want duplicated names/IDs.

Is this the correct syntax to tell the validator plugin not to validate an input that has that class?

Comment: What does your HTML for the *field* look like? According to [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), what you have should work.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.  The plugin will not even validate any element unless it has a `name` attribute.

Comment: The correct way to clone an item with a `name` or `id` is to use an index number and increment it every time the item is cloned, not eliminate the `name` or `id`.  Simply use jQuery to change the `name` or `id` accordingly after cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was actually the success function that was defined, on removing that everything was much better behaved...

```
        success: function (element) {
            element.prev().attr('class', 'valid');
        }
```